# how to submit multiple fields in form data :ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have input fields like this, as per below pic:

[image]

raw data:

```
{
    "title": "",
    "slug": "",
    "image": "",
    "description": ""
}
```

As you can see per above image, the endpoint url: http://localhost:8000/api/create

my whole idea is whenever user input their value in the fields(as you can see above pic) and if the user will heat the submit button then data will be insert in the database.

I am probably new to ReactJS. it would be great, if anybody could help me out where i'm doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
               super(props);
               this.state ={
               file:null
             }
             this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
             this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
             this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
             }
             onFormSubmit(e){
             e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
             this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response)=>{
             console.log(response.data);
             })
             }
            onChange(e) {
            this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
            }

            const title = document.querySelector('#title') ;
            const slug = document.querySelector('#slug') ;
            const image = document.querySelector('#image') ;
            const desc = document.querySelector('#description') ;

            const formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('title', title.value);
            formData.append('slug', slug.value);
            formData.append('image', image.files[0]);
            formData.append('description', desc.value);

            const options = {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData
            };

            fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/create', options);

        render(){

        return(

            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <h1>File Upload</h1>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
               <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
               <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
               <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
              </form>
            </div>

            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the syntax error that you have been getting?

Comment: I highly suggest you go through `React` docs on how to handle forms - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html - what you're doing here is not correct and shouldn't even work. Once you figure out how to deal with forms in `React`, look through this example - https://gist.github.com/AshikNesin/e44b1950f6a24cfcd85330ffc1713513

Comment: Remove the extra `}` from your code after `body: formData,`. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `}` in you code after `body: formData,`, So fix that

```
.....
const options = {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: formData,
                };
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/create', options);
```

EDIT

You are writing the code inside the return statement with `jsx`. Move it outside. Even then, you should probably move this logic outside the render method

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{



 render(){
    const title = document.querySelector('#title') ;
    const slug = document.querySelector('#slug') ;
    const image = document.querySelector('#image') ;
    const desc = document.querySelector('#description') ;

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('title', title.value);
    formData.append('slug', slug.value);
    formData.append('image', image.files[0]);
    formData.append('description', desc.value);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/create', options);

    return (<div></div>)
  }
}
```

**EDIT - V2**

So there are a lot of mistakes in your code, Check the code below and see if it works. I couldn't test it from my side due to some issues.

You had written the `constructor` and other methods that you wanted to be class members inside the `render` method. And you had written the `formData` preparation code without any function which would eventually be a syntax error so I have put that code inside the `onFormSubmit` function

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            file:null,
            title: "",
            slug: "",
            description: ""
        }
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        //  this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit

        // const title = document.querySelector('#title') ;
        // const slug = document.querySelector('#slug') ;
        // const image = document.querySelector('#image') ;
        // const desc = document.querySelector('#description') ;

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('title', this.state.title);
        formData.append('slug', this.state.slug);
        formData.append('image', this.state.file);
        formData.append('description', this.state.description);

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/create', options);


        // this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response)=>{
        //     console.log(response.data);
        // })
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
    }


    render(){
        return(

            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <input name="title" type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({title: e.target.value})}} />
                <input name="slug" type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({slug: e.target.value})}} />
                <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
                <input name="description" type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({description: e.target.value})}} />
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
              </form>
            </div>

            )
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, even i cleared that, still i am getting the same issue. i have updated my question. please take a look again at my question.

Comment: Is is the same `Syntax Error`? Can you show the whole Error Message?

Comment: See the Edit, You were writing the statements inside the `return` statement

Comment: great! thank you again for guide me. now how to insert the values in the form data?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You are returning a blank `<div />` from `render`. What do you mean by `how do i insert values`? Where is the data coming from? When should the `formData` be submitted?

Comment: as per i told you i'm not a reactJS developer. i'm beginner at reactJS. i have no idea how to do this all. my whole idea is whenever user input their value in the fields(as you can see above pic) and if the user will heat the submit button then data will be insert in the database.

Comment: Where is the code of the Screen that you have shown in your post? Is that also written in react?

Comment: hey there, i have edited my question. please take a look again. @MD.TabishMahfuz

Comment: @bounty Please see the Edit

Comment: `onChange(e) {
        this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
    }`    syantax error: 'e' is not defined.

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a mistake from my side. You must provide a parameter in the onchange events. Please see again. I've edited my answer

Comment: thank you so much. it's really helped me :) @MD.TabishMahfuz

Comment: Glad I could help! Try and understand the mistakes and ask you have any concerns

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    .  Hopefully you can help me here. Thanxx!!

Comment: is there a way to prevent those multiple .appends somehow?

Comment: @SavannahMadison There is no predefined function that would allow you to set multiple fields at once except if you already have a Form Element in a JS Variable then you can pass that in the constructor. You can use a custom function like `const createFormData = data => {
    return Object.keys(data).reduce((formData, key) => {
        formData.append(key, data[key]);
        return formData;
    }, new FormData());
}`

Answer (score 1):

`title` field is a file too? i don't think that!

```js
const title = document.querySelector('#title') ;
const slug = document.querySelector('#slug') ;
const image = document.querySelector('#image') ;
const desc = document.querySelector('#description') ;

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('title', title.value);
formData.append('slug', slug.value);
formData.append('image', image.files[0]);
formData.append('description', desc.value);
```

and you write a extra `}` on this section of code:

```js
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  }
};
```

Comment: yes i did a common mistake, thank you for guide me.  now i'm getting the same error at `method:POST`

Comment: yes, even i cleared that, still i am getting the same issue. i have updated my question. please take a look again.

Comment: do you have windows? if yes remove node_modules and package-lock.json and install agian

Comment: hey there, i have edited my question. please take a look again @Hamid

Comment: you write constructor and other functions inside of render method, move these codes out of render

Comment: do you use any remote server application like teamviewer or anydesk?

Comment: i have anydesk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213780/discussion-between-hamid-sarani-and-bounty).

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    .  Hopefully you can help me here. Thanxx!!

Answer (score 0):

Better approach **cOMPLETE sOLUTION**

```js
class PostPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      content: "",
      category: "",
      tags: [],
      thumbnail: null,
      approvalCode: "",
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      thumbnail: e.target.files[0]
    });
  }
  async handleSubmit(e) {
    const createFormData = (data) => {
      return Object.keys(data).reduce((formData, key) => {
        formData.append(key, data[key]);
        return formData;
      }, new FormData());
    };
    const data = createFormData(this.state);

    const newPost = await Axios.post("http://localhost:4001/post/new", data);
    console.log(newPost);
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      Container >
      <
      Form >
      <
      input name = "title"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.setState({
          title: e.target.value
        })
      }
      placeholder = "Title..." /
      >
      <
      input name = "content"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.setState({
          content: e.target.value
        })
      }
      placeholder = "Write article here..." /
      >
      <
      select name = "category"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.setState({
          category: e.target.value
        })
      } >
      <
      option selected disabled >
      Select category <
      /option> <
      option value = "Business" > Business < /option> <
      option value = "Advert" > Advert < /option> <
      option value = "Update" > Update < /option> <
      option value = "Strateg" > Strategy < /option> <
      /select> <
      input name = "tags"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.setState({
          tags: e.target.value
        })
      }
      placeholder = "Add tags seperate with comma" /
      >
      <
      input name = "thumbnail"
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      accept = "image/*"
      type = "file" /
      >
      <
      input name = "approvalCode"
      onChange = {
        (e) => this.setState({
          approvalCode: e.target.value
        })
      }
      type = "password"
      placeholder = "Approval code" /
      >
      <
      button type = "submit"
      onClick = {
        this.handleSubmit
      } >
      Publish <
      /button> <
      /Form> <
      /Container>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
               super(props);
               this.state ={
               file:null
             }
             this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
             this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
             this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
             }
             onFormSubmit(e){
             e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
             this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response)=>{
             console.log(response.data);
             })
             }
            onChange(e) {
            this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
            }

            const title = document.querySelector('#title') ;
            const slug = document.querySelector('#slug') ;
            const image = document.querySelector('#image') ;
            const desc = document.querySelector('#description') ;

            const formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('title', title.value);
            formData.append('slug', slug.value);
            formData.append('image', image.files[0]);
            formData.append('description', desc.value);

            const options = {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData
            };

            fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/create', options);

        render(){

        return(

            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <h1>File Upload</h1>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
               <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
               <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
               <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
              </form>
            </div>

            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).